# Can someone explain how to integrate it? $\int\frac{(x^2+1)dx}{x\sqrt{x^4+3x^3-2x^2-3x+1}},x>1$

Tags: integration

Can someone explain how to integrate it?

$$\int\frac{(x^2+1)dx}{x\sqrt{x^4+3x^3-2x^2-3x+1}},x>1$$
I know that I should use a substitution but I can't figure out. I should make some transformations under the root.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try it using wolfram alpha?

Comment: I know that I should use a substitution but I can't figure out. I should make some transformations under the root

Comment: Hint: the expression in the square root is a perfect square

Comment: @jgd1729 you meat that we have (x^2-1)(x^2+3x-1) under the root?

Comment: @James I mean that we have $(x^2 +\frac{3}{2}x-1)^2$ under the root.

Comment: @James I enclosed your comment into the question so that your effort can be seen..

Comment: No, it is not a perfect square @jgd1729

Comment: @MathFail you are correct, I did the algebra too quickly and missed a term

Comment: @jgd1729 it will be coefficient under root 1/4 with x^2 not a 2

Comment: @coffeemath it gives me wrong answer

Comment: @CrSb0001 I think that I need get sqrt(t^2+k) under the root on last stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{x^4+3x^3-2x^2-3x+1}}dx\\~\\＝\int\;\frac {\frac {1}{x^2}＋1}{x\sqrt {1＋\frac {3}{x}－\frac {2}{x^2}-\frac {3}{x^3}＋\frac {1}{x^4}}}dx\\~\\＝\int\;\frac {\frac {1}{x^2}＋1}{\sqrt {x^2＋3x－2-\frac {3}{x}＋\frac {1}{x^2}}}dx\\~\\＝\int\;\frac {\frac {1}{x^2}＋1}{\sqrt {\left({x-\frac {1}{x}}\right)^2＋3\left({x-\frac {1}{x}}\right)}}dx$$

Now : let u = $x-\frac{1}{x}$

**Just a start, now try to complete the solution on your own.  I think you can do that.**

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Can you help me with another one, please? You can find question in my profile.

Comment: I have answered your question

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{x^2+1}{x\sqrt{x^4+3x^3-2x^2-3x+1}}dx\\
=&\int\frac{1+\frac1{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+3x-2-\frac3{x}+\frac1{x^2}}}dx 
=\int\frac{d(x-\frac1{x})}{\sqrt{(x-\frac1x)^2+3(x-\frac1x)}}\\ \end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much!